# According to the selected value of drop box I need to change the another field value in laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Where should I implement the logic? I mean inside which class? It was not work in the controller method? SO can anybody help me please

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());

    });
    $('#Orange').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());
    });
    $('#Red').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());
    });
    $('#Green').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: why not use jquery or vue.js?

Comment: I am not familiar with them. Can you give me the help with code for it?

Comment: will post it below

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have  with id 'select1' and 'select2'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').on('change',function(){
        $('#color').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Here, how I assigned this variable(selected) to form field. My form field looks like below                                                                                             {!! Form::hidden('color',$val) !!}

Comment: And also my drop down list like below.                                                                     {!! Form::select('type', array('type' => 'type','Orange' => 'Orange', 'Red' => 'Red','Green' => 'Green'), 'type') !!}                                                                                   So what can I take as the id?

Comment: so what do you need to do exactly? make selected element the one that in hidden input?

Comment: For the time being, I need to send the selected drop down value for hidden input variable

Comment: I've edited answer
just please not that you have ID attribute in your hidden field as well as in your select,if not pass that with array

Comment: Then it will generate an exception regarding Undefined variable: val.

Comment: that is because you're not sening $val as data to that view,if you don't need that just do - Form::hidden('color',null) !!} or pass $val variable to your view

Comment: Then hidden input value get null. I want to set the value of it to the selected drop box value

Comment: For the time being I need to set the hidden input field value to selected drop down box value

Comment: Yeah. It will not set value of hidden field and post to the controller method to insert into the db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107745/discussion-between-a-wen-and-hrach).